# python garbage collection about list append itself

Tags: python

```
a = [2]
a.append(a)
```

And I print a,

```
[2, [...]]
```

Also I print a[1][0]

```
2
```

What is `[...]` ? and when I print `a[1][0]`, print 2, not `[...]` ?

Comment: `[...]` means that it's a list but the `print` not displaying its content.

Comment: good question, but I'm puzzled about the title. What's to do with garbage collection?

Comment: I am watching Python Tutorial, garbage collection youtube, that code is in there. so I think that code is related to garbage collection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`...` is the [*ellipsis object*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=ellipsis#the-ellipsis-object). Here it is issued because else it would print forever! (due to infinite recursion)

and: `print(a[1][0])`:

`a[1]` is `a` so `a[1][0]` is 2, like `a[1][1][1][1][0]` is 2 too.

Comment: I just edited. Ellipsis operator is something else. I'll use your link. and it's _not_ pedantic. Thank you very much.

Comment: Thanks ! and, It means [2, [2, [2, [2, ~ ]], is it right?

Comment: A bit like the larsen you'd get when you're filming your own TV while feeding your image to it :) Actually it means "there are other things but I cannot show them". But it could be issued in other situations.

Answer (score 2):

Ellipsis `...` is used for slicing multidimensional numpy arrays.

The ellipsis syntax may be used to indicate selecting in full any remaining unspecified dimensions.

`a[1]` is `[2, [...]]`

so, `a[1][0]` is `2`.